# Enable broker service asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have to enable broker service to use notification in my application `ASP.Net MVC` with local database entity Framework Code first, I tried `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`

The error was:

> Msg 5011, Level 14, State 5, Line 1 User does not have permission to
>   alter database 'DATA', the database does not exist, or the database is
>   not in a state that allows access checks. Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Comment: i tried also" ALTER DATABASE BlogDemos SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ;" and i had the same error

Comment: you can put your code on the question content it will be useful for us to deal with your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to GRANT ALTER DATABASE permission to the user who is running SQL command.

```
GRANT ALTER ON DATABASE::DatabaseName TO username;
```

Comment: i try it "  GRANT ALTER ON DATABASE:: DbCvTech TO myUser;" my webconfig is  <add name="CvtechDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\USERS\TECHNICA\DOCUMENTS\DbCvTech.MDF;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True ;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />     but i have error Cannot find the database 'DbCvTech', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.